# Extract subimage of CVImageBufferRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, avcapturesession

I simply want to extract a small area of a YUV 420 image. That is, create a CVImageBufferRef from a CVImageBufferRef which only contains a rectangular part of the original image.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
- (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBufferRef fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    // callback from AVCaptureOutput
    //
    CVImageBufferRef imageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBufferRef);
    if (imageBufferRef)
    {
        // Take a subset of buffer to create a smaller image 
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBufferRef, 0);
        size_t widthY = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 0);
        size_t widthUV = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 1);
        size_t heightY = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 0);
        size_t heightUV = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 1);
        size_t cropHeightY = 320;
        size_t cropWidthY = 320;
        size_t cropHeightUV = cropHeightY / 2;
        size_t cropWidthUV = cropWidthY;
        size_t cropY_X0 = widthY / 2 - (cropWidthY / 2);
        size_t cropY_Y0 = heightY / 2 - (cropHeightY / 2);
        size_t cropUV_X0 = widthUV / 2 - (cropWidthUV / 2);
        size_t cropUV_Y0 = heightUV / 2 - (cropHeightUV / 2);

        void *baseAddressY = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 0);
        void *baseAddressUV = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 1);

        size_t bytesPerRowY = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 0);
        size_t bytesPerRowUV = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 1);

        size_t pixelBytesY = bytesPerRowY / widthY;
        size_t pixelBytesUV = bytesPerRowUV / widthUV;

        void *startPosY = baseAddressY + (cropY_Y0 * bytesPerRowY + cropY_X0 * pixelBytesY);
        void *startPosUV = baseAddressUV + (cropUV_Y0 * bytesPerRowUV + cropUV_X0 * pixelBytesUV);

        size_t bytesPerRowOut = cropWidthY * pixelBytesY;

        size_t sizeY = bytesPerRowOut * cropHeightY;
        size_t sizeUV = bytesPerRowOut * cropHeightUV;

        unsigned char * pixelY = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeY);
        unsigned char * pixelUV = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeUV);

        for (int i = 0; i < cropHeightY; ++i) {
            memcpy(pixelY + i * bytesPerRowOut, startPosY + i * bytesPerRowY, bytesPerRowOut);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < cropHeightUV; ++i) {
            memcpy(pixelUV + i * bytesPerRowOut, startPosUV + i * bytesPerRowUV, bytesPerRowOut);
        }

        void *baseAddresses[2] = {pixelY, pixelUV};
        size_t planeWidths[2] = {cropWidthY, cropWidthUV};
        size_t planeHeights[2] = {cropHeightY, cropHeightUV};
        size_t planeBytesPerRow[2] = {bytesPerRowOut, bytesPerRowOut};

        // create a new CVImageBufferRef from pixelY and pixelUV
        CVPixelBufferRef outBuff;
        CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(NULL, cropWidthY, cropHeightY, '420v', NULL, 0, 2, baseAddresses, planeWidths, planeHeights, planeBytesPerRow, NULL, NULL, NULL, &outBuff);

        if(logCameraSettings) {
            NSLog(@"Original Image Size:\n   width:%zu\n   height:%zu\n", widthY, heightY);
            size_t outWidthY = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(outBuff, 0);
            size_t outHeightY = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(outBuff, 0);
            NSLog(@"Modified Image Size:\n   width:%zu\n   height:%zu\n", outWidthY, outHeightY);
        }

        // Here would be the place where I actually want to do something with the image

        // TEST: show image (in debugger in following method)
        [self convertToUIImage:imageBufferRef]; // --> works
        [self convertToUIImage:outBuff]; // --> only gray, does not work

        // Release the allocated memory
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBufferRef,0);
        free(pixelY);
        free(pixelUV);
    }
}

-(void) convertToUIImage:(CVImageBufferRef)imageBuffer
{
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];
    CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef videoImage = [temporaryContext
                             createCGImage:ciImage
                             fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))];

    // Inspect the following UIImage in debugger.
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:videoImage];

    CGImageRelease(videoImage);
}
```

In the above code I created a small function convertToUIImage which has no purpose except to let me inspect the CVImageBufferRef I created as a UIImage in the debugger.

Inspecting imageBufferRef shows me the correct camera feed.

Inspecting outBuff does however not show me a small area of that camera feed but an all gray patch of the correct size.

So my question is:

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. Is this even the correct way to go to achieve my goal?

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it

```
- (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBufferRef fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    // callback from AVCaptureOutput
    //
    CVImageBufferRef imageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBufferRef);
    if (imageBufferRef)
    {
        // Take a subset of buffer to create a smaller image
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBufferRef, 0);
        size_t widthY = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 0);
        size_t widthUV = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 1);
        size_t heightY = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 0);
        size_t heightUV = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 1);
        size_t cropHeightY = 500;
        size_t cropWidthY = 500;
        size_t cropHeightUV = cropHeightY / 2;
        size_t cropWidthUV = cropWidthY;
        size_t cropY_X0 = widthY / 2 - (cropWidthY / 2);
        size_t cropY_Y0 = heightY / 2 - (cropHeightY / 2);
        size_t cropUV_X0 = widthUV / 2 - (cropWidthUV / 2);
        size_t cropUV_Y0 = heightUV / 2 - (cropHeightUV / 2);

        void *baseAddressY = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 0);
        void *baseAddressUV = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 1);

        size_t bytesPerRowY = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 0);
        size_t bytesPerRowUV = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBufferRef, 1);

        size_t pixelBytesY = bytesPerRowY / widthY;
        size_t pixelBytesUV = bytesPerRowUV / widthUV;

        void *startPosY = baseAddressY + (cropY_Y0 * bytesPerRowY + cropY_X0 * pixelBytesY);
        void *startPosUV = baseAddressUV + (cropUV_Y0 * bytesPerRowUV + cropUV_X0 * pixelBytesUV);

        size_t bytesPerRowOut = cropWidthY * pixelBytesY;

        size_t sizeY = bytesPerRowOut * cropHeightY;
        size_t sizeUV = bytesPerRowOut * cropHeightUV;

        unsigned char * pixelY = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeY);
        unsigned char * pixelUV = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeUV);

        for (int i = 0; i < cropHeightY; ++i) {
            memcpy(pixelY + i * bytesPerRowOut, startPosY + i * bytesPerRowY, bytesPerRowOut);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < cropHeightUV; ++i) {
            memcpy(pixelUV + i * bytesPerRowOut, startPosUV + i * bytesPerRowUV, bytesPerRowOut);
        }

        void *baseAddresses[2] = {pixelY, pixelUV};
        size_t planeWidths[2] = {cropWidthY, cropWidthUV};
        size_t planeHeights[2] = {cropHeightY, cropHeightUV};
        size_t planeBytesPerRow[2] = {bytesPerRowOut, bytesPerRowOut};

        // Transform input to UIImage
        UIImage *inputAsUIImage = [self convertToUIImage:imageBufferRef];

        // Extract subimage of UIImage
        CGRect fromRect = CGRectMake(cropY_X0, cropY_Y0, cropWidthY, cropHeightY); // or whatever rectangle
        CGImageRef drawImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(inputAsUIImage.CGImage, fromRect);
        UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:drawImage];
        CGImageRelease(drawImage);

        // Convert UIImage back to CVImageBufferRef
        // 1. Create a CIImage with the underlying CGImage encapsulated by the UIImage (referred to as 'image'):
        CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage.CGImage];
        // 2. Create a CIContext:
        CIContext *ciContext = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() options:nil];
        // 3. Render the CIImage to a CVPixelBuffer (referred to as 'outputBuffer'):
        CVPixelBufferRef outputBuffer;
        CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(NULL, cropWidthY, cropHeightY, '420v', NULL, 0, 2, baseAddresses, planeWidths, planeHeights, planeBytesPerRow, NULL, NULL, NULL, &outputBuffer);
        [ciContext render:inputImage toCVPixelBuffer:outputBuffer];


        if(logCameraSettings) {
            NSLog(@"Original Image Size:\n   width:%zu\n   height:%zu\n", widthY, heightY);
            size_t outWidthY = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(outputBuffer, 0);
            size_t outHeightY = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(outputBuffer, 0);
            NSLog(@"Modified Image Size:\n   width:%zu\n   height:%zu\n", outWidthY, outHeightY);
        }

        // Do something with it here

        // Release the allocated memory
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBufferRef,0);
        free(pixelY);
        free(pixelUV);
    }
}

-(UIImage*) convertToUIImage:(CVImageBufferRef)imageBuffer
{
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];
    CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef videoImage = [temporaryContext
                             createCGImage:ciImage
                             fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:videoImage];

    CGImageRelease(videoImage);
    return image;
}
```